# JS recursive function: works fine with no recursion, returns answer plus "Undefined" when recursion used

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm currently working with the following recursive function. Its role is to assign 3 items to 3 "sectors", using recursion to re-run the function until every item is assigned to its own sector. It works fine the 2/9 times when each item is assigned to an empty slot on its first try, but if the function uses recursion, it displays (when I display, using console.log, the variable that is supposed to be returned) first the proper coordinates and then an array [undefined, undefined], which seems to overwrite the proper coordinates as the result variable. The function then returns [undefined, undefined].

Below is an example of my console.log output. As you can see, the undefined result only happens if the function is called multiple times. Weirdly though, the function does work (at first) in those cases - island_core is assigned to real coordinates - it just then replaces those working coordinates with an [undefined, undefined]. My code is displayed below the console output.

Anyone know how to address this? Thanks so much for any help you can give!

Console.log output:

```
ASSIGNING ISLAND 1
Island sector distributor: 0.4996039977514938
Water top full: false
Water mid full: false
Water bottom full: false
Assigned sector mid
Island core: 145.7255743052315, 628.1824251323584
ASSIGNING ISLAND 2
Island sector distributor: 0.4175444925572739
Water top full: false
Water mid full: true
Water bottom full: false 
Island sector distributor: 0.9873914243694555 
Water top full: false
Water mid full: true 
Water bottom full: false 
Assigned sector bottom 
Island core: 227.29271060663325, 819.4032413102415
Island core: undefined, undefined
undefined
ASSIGNING ISLAND 3
Island sector distributor: 0.8861211980050283 
Water top full: false 
Water mid full: true
Water bottom full: true
Island sector distributor: 0.8407451988967638 
Water top full: false 
Water mid full: true
Water bottom full: true
Island sector distributor: 0.32777241987116223
Water top full: false
Water mid full: true
Water bottom full: true
Assigned sector top
Island core: 207.65905036573935, 173.1130653613051
Island core: undefined, undefined
```

Code (code within each assignment statement seems to be working - it just randomly assigns a set of coordinates within a set range).

```js
var water_top_full = false;
var water_mid_full = false;
var water_bottom_full = false;

//Make a recursive function that assigns islands to sectors,
//and reassigns if an island is assigned to a full sector.

var assign_island_sector = function(){
 var island_sector_distributor = Math.random();
 //Object for island_core
 var island_core = [];
 console.log("Island sector distributor: " + island_sector_distributor);
 console.log("Water top full: " + water_top_full);
 console.log("Water mid full: " + water_mid_full);
 console.log("Water bottom full: " + water_bottom_full);
 if (island_sector_distributor <= (1/3)){
  if (water_top_full == false){
   island_core[1] = (Math.random() * 100);
   //Upper/lower boundaries for island core expectation
   //Change higher or lower based on how close islands get to the shore
   var core_upper_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] + 50);
   //Check to make sure that top-sector lower values don't go below 0:
   var core_lower_limit;
   if (island_core[1] < 50){
    core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1]);
   }
   else{
    core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] - 50);
   }
   island_core[0] = (Math.random() * 100);
   water_top_full = true;
   console.log("Assigned sector top");
   //return island_core;
  }
  else if (water_top_full == true){
   assign_island_sector();
  }
 }
 else if ((island_sector_distributor > (1/3)) && (island_sector_distributor <= (2/3))){
  if (water_mid_full == false){
   island_core[1] = (100 + (Math.random() * 100));
   //Upper/lower boundaries for island core expectation
   //Change higher or lower based on how close islands get to the shore
   var core_upper_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] + 50);
   var core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] - 50);
   island_core[0] = (Math.random() * 100);
   water_mid_full = true;
   console.log("Assigned sector mid");
   //return island_core;
  }
  else if (water_mid_full == true){
   assign_island_sector();
  }
 }
 else if (island_sector_distributor > (2/3)){
  if (water_bottom_full == false){
   island_core[1] = (200 + (Math.random() * 100));
   core_upper_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] + 50);
   var core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] - 50);
   island_core[0] = (Math.random() * 100);
   water_bottom_full = true;
   console.log("Assigned sector bottom");
   //return island_core;
  }
  else if (water_bottom_full == true){
   assign_island_sector();
  }
 }

 console.log("Island core: " + island_core[0] + ", " + island_core[1]);
 
 return island_core;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
 
 console.log("ASSIGNING ISLAND " + (i + 1));
 var island_center = assign_island_sector();
 for (var p = 0; p < 2; p++){
  console.log(island_center[p]);
 }
}
```

EDIT: added where I call the function, sorry about that. All it does it assign the returned function value (supposed to be an array with x and y coordinates) into a new variable, which I then use going forward.

Comment: Could you please edit the code snippet so that you actually call the function?

Comment: Just added it on the end. I can add more of the next part if that would help, but I don't think there's a way that could be part of the problem, as the issue is that the function itself is returning an array [undefined, undefined].

Comment: Could you please edit the code snippet so that it displays the same behavior you're describing? Click the *"Run code snippet"* button before posting and check that it a) doesn't throw an error and b) displays the same output that you have earlier in the question.

Comment: The snippet needs a closing bracket at the least line.

Comment: Your snippet does not work so it's hard to tell, but you can run your code through a linter like https://jshint.com it might help you find some mistakes

Comment: Still new to this site and JS, just edited the snippet to get it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is confuse for me.

But the `undefied` in `console.log` is because you are not setting the return of the recursive call to your `island_core` variable -- so it's printing fine in the first time and printing `undefined` in second time.

Try to do it:

`island_core = assign_island_sector();`

**EDITED**

```js
var water_top_full = false;
var water_mid_full = false;
var water_bottom_full = false;

//Make a recursive function that assigns islands to sectors,
//and reassigns if an island is assigned to a full sector.

var assign_island_sector = function(){
  var island_sector_distributor = Math.random();
  //Object for island_core
  var island_core = [];
  console.log("Island sector distributor: " + island_sector_distributor);
  console.log("Water top full: " + water_top_full);
  console.log("Water mid full: " + water_mid_full);
  console.log("Water bottom full: " + water_bottom_full);
  if (island_sector_distributor <= (1/3)){
    if (water_top_full == false){
      island_core[1] = (Math.random() * 100);
      //Upper/lower boundaries for island core expectation
      //Change higher or lower based on how close islands get to the shore
      var core_upper_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] + 50);
      //Check to make sure that top-sector lower values don't go below 0:
      var core_lower_limit;
      if (island_core[1] < 50){
        core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1]);
      }
      else{
        core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] - 50);
      }
      island_core[0] = (Math.random() * 100);
      water_top_full = true;
      console.log("Assigned sector top");
      //return island_core;
    }
    else if (water_top_full == true){
      island_core = assign_island_sector();
    }
  }
  else if ((island_sector_distributor > (1/3)) && (island_sector_distributor <= (2/3))){
    if (water_mid_full == false){
      island_core[1] = (100 + (Math.random() * 100));
      //Upper/lower boundaries for island core expectation
      //Change higher or lower based on how close islands get to the shore
      var core_upper_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] + 50);
      var core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] - 50);
      island_core[0] = (Math.random() * 100);
      water_mid_full = true;
      console.log("Assigned sector mid");
      //return island_core;
    }
    else if (water_mid_full == true){
      island_core = assign_island_sector();
    }
  }
  else if (island_sector_distributor > (2/3)){
    if (water_bottom_full == false){
      island_core[1] = (200 + (Math.random() * 100));
      core_upper_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] + 50);
      var core_lower_limit = Math.round(island_core[1] - 50);
      island_core[0] = (Math.random() * 100);
      water_bottom_full = true;
      console.log("Assigned sector bottom");
      //return island_core;
    }
    else if (water_bottom_full == true){
      island_core = assign_island_sector();
    }
  }

  console.log("Island core: " + island_core[0] + ", " + island_core[1]);
  
  return island_core;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  
  console.log("ASSIGNING ISLAND " + (i + 1));
  var island_center = assign_island_sector();
  for (var p = 0; p < 2; p++){
    console.log(island_center[p]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look if it's printing what is expected?

Comment: Thanks so much, I changed the lines in my else-if recursion clauses from assign_island_sector(); to island_core = assign_island_sector(); and now the code is working perfectly. Sorry if this was a basic mistake.